# Add Action to Button in Lightning VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, button, action

I have a button that I want to redirect to another page here is the button:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-float_none slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-small" title="Edit this Field" action="{!gotoPage}">
```

Then the controller has this in it:

```
    public with sharing class PricingRequest{

public string oppid {get;set;
  public pagereference getgotopage()
{
    oppid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
    pagereference pr = new PageReference('/apex/TestPage2');
    pr.getParameters().put('oppid',oppid);
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    return pr;
    }
```

}

But it is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am receiving Invalid Regular Expression Flags from the browse when I click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this line

```
 public PageReference gotopage{get;set;}
```

and rename the method gotopage() into getgotopage() in apex but do not change {!gotopage} in visualforce.

Remove also

```
  pr.setRedirect(false);
```

Then it should work.

Comment: When i do that I receive an error saying on my visualforce page there is a reference to gotopage... The property System.PageReference gotopage is referenced by Visualforce Page (TestPage) in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 3 column 26

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: that worked to get rid of the error but when I click the button nothing occurs still

Comment: Updated again my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help.. Since I am in Lightning I believe Page Reference does not work to redirect. My issue though is now when I redirect using sforce.one.navigateToURL the entire page reloads instead of the frame that the visualforce page is in on the record tab

Comment: the redirect should work fine in the iframe